# How to send Newsletter email with images in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html-email

I am trying send Newsletter with images, I am able to send email but not getting images, I tried to search lots of solution but its not working.Please check this link for [Simple Newsletter](http://shooters.com.au/Newsletter/newsletter.html)

When I am trying to email this newsletter, I am getting newsletter without images. I put hard coded images in html file, like `<img src=http://www.abc.com/images/xyz.jpg />`
Here my simple code for sending email :

```
MailMessage myMail;

    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("Newsletter.html"))) // Path to your 
    {                                                         // HTML file
        myMail = new MailMessage();
        myMail.From = new MailAddress("email@domain.com.au");
        myMail.Subject = "Test News Letter";
        myMail.To.Add("se@yahoo.com.au");
        myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        myMail.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();  // Load the content from your file...

    }
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("xx.xx.xx.y", 25);
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com.au", "hakoo");
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = cred;
    smtp.Send(myMail);
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issues?

Thanks,

Hakoo Desai.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images in MHT files from MS Word do not display in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321456/images-in-mht-files-from-ms-word-do-not-display-in-email)

Comment: u need to encode all images with base 64 encoding and send email